# CVE-2021-44228 and log4j 1.2.17

Tags: security, logging, log4j

I am on log4j 1.2.17, we use (apache-log4j-extras as well - same version).

Could you please advice me if CVE-2021-44228 impacts this version or not?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to mitigate log4shell vulnerability in version 1.2 of log4j?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70312033/how-to-mitigate-log4shell-vulnerability-in-version-1-2-of-log4j)

Comment: With log4j 1.x, you are affected by CVE-2021-4104 and CVE-2019-17571 which may have similar impact. As such, you may want to upgrade regardless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [specific vulnerability](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2021-44228) is not present there. See http://slf4j.org/log4shell.html:

> Is log4j 1.x vulnerable?
> As log4j 1.x does not offer a look-up mechanism, it does not suffer from CVE-2021-44228. However, note that log4j 1.x is no longer being maintained. Thus, we urge you to migrate to one of its successors such as SLF4J and logback. Do migrate without delaying too much!
> Given that log4j version 1.x is still very widely deployed, we have been receiving a steady stream of questions regarding the vulnerability of log4j version 1.x.
>
> **As log4j 1.x does not offer a look up mechanism, it does not suffer from CVE-2021-44228.**
>
> Having said this, log4j 1.x is no longer being maintained with all the entailed security implications. Thus, we definitely urge you to migrate to one of its successors such as SLF4J/logback, sooner rather than later. But do migrate without waiting for months! Also note that tools exist to automate the migration.

Comment: Reload4j 1.2.18.0 has been released. It is as a replacement for log4j version 1.2.17 with fixes for CVE-2021-4104 and CVE-2019-17571.

Answer (score 1):

For versions 1.x.x of log4j you are vulnerable **only** if you are using a JMS Appender in your log4j configuration. [Description of the vulnerability and possible mitigations of cve-2021-44228](https://tutoref.com/cve-2021-44228-zero-day-vulnerability/) are explained here.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by [MA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70334973/100970), as log4j 1.x does not offer a look up mechanism, it does **not** suffer from CVE-2021-44228. See also https://www.slf4j.org/log4shell.html

It should also be mentioned that the [reload4j](https://reload4j.qos.ch) project fixes outstanding vulnerabilities with log4j 1.x.