# Updating log4j1.2 to log4j2 present in lib hadoop-mapreduce-client-core

Tags: hadoop, log4j, log4j2

I need to exclude log4j1.2 dependency from `hadoop-mapreduce-client-core` lib and explicitly include log4j2 version in my pom but there is no upgraded version available for the below and log4j2 is backward incompatible with 3.3.0 version

```
<groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
<artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-core</artifactId>
<version>3.3.0</version>
```

Please suggest if we have any workaround

Answer (score 2):

This is mostly a rehash of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70310980/log4j-vulnerability-is-log4j-1-2-17-vulnerable-was-unable-to-find-any-jndi-co).  I'm not marking as duplicate because it has a hadoop spin.

You can't arbitrarily upgrade a log4j file and hope it fixes things.  Here's the prescribed way to remove the vulnerability:

> While not affected by the exact same Log4Shell issue, the Apache
> Log4j team recommends to remove JMSAppender and SocketServer, which
> has a vulnerability in [CVE-2019-17571](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70310980/log4j-vulnerability-is-log4j-1-2-17-vulnerable-was-unable-to-find-any-jndi-co), from your JAR files.
>
> You can use the zip command to remove the affected classes. Replace the filename/version with yours:
>
> ```
>     zip -d log4j-1.2.16.jar org/apache/log4j/net/JMSAppender.class 
>     zip -d log4j-1.2.16.jar org/apache/log4j/net/SocketServer.class
> ```
>
> You can look through through the files in your zip using less and grep, e.g. `less log4j-1.2.16.jar | grep JMSAppender`

I hope it's obvious that you would just change the specific version from `log4j-1.2.16.jar` to `log4j-[your version].jar`.

If you don't want to do that you'd need to upgrade log4j2 in hadoop core and build a version from that. (@OneCricketeer thanks for the correction)

Comment: _should have been removed from that version_ - Do you have a JIRA / PR that says this is the case?

Comment: Bad assumption on my part that Hadoop would have patched this.  @OneCricketeer thanks for the correction.

Comment: I meant, it _might have been_. I have not been following the changes

Comment: Actually, https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core has not yet updated to comply with the latest log4j2